# Latest Android emulator doesn't work anymore when running a virtual ARM device on a x86 host

Tags: android, arm, emulation, qemu

I am running Ubuntu 23.10 on a Ryzen 3700x with a Nvidia 1050Ti GPU and on this host I am using four VMs inside Android Studio / virtual Device Manager for the platforms x86-32, x86-64, Armv7 and Arm64-v8 all of them running some android image. This worked fine with the older emulator 31.xxx although Arm VMs are damn slow of course but this doesn't matter for my use-case.

Now after updating the emulator to latest version 33.1.24 and even after reinstalling latest version of Android studio completely the two Arm-based VMs don't start anymore while the two x86-based VMs still work fine.

Console shows these errors:

```
2024-01-02 13:40:58,080 [ 374468] SEVERE - Emulator: armv8 - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code 139
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:202)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:252)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy36.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:226)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessTerminatedListener.processTerminated(ProcessTerminatedListener.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:252)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy36.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.lambda$notifyTerminated$2(ProcessHandler.java:210)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:285)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:193)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:189)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseProcessHandler.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$1.lambda$startNotified$0(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:84)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$0(ProcessWaitFor.java:45)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:227)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$1(ProcessWaitFor.java:23)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2024-01-02 13:40:58,084 [ 374472] SEVERE - Emulator: armv8 - Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1  Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11076708
2024-01-02 13:40:58,084 [ 374472] SEVERE - Emulator: armv8 - JDK: 17.0.7; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2024-01-02 13:40:58,085 [ 374473] SEVERE - Emulator: armv8 - OS: Linux
```

Nvidia drivers of host are already updated to latest version 535, trying different settings for the "emulated performance / graphics" didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Edit: I found older emulator 31.x in some download archive and it fixed my problem. But anyway it might be of some interest at Google fixing this regression.

Comment: You did not tell what exit code 139 means.

Comment: @blackapps How should I know what this exit code means? When you google "Emulator terminated with exit code 139" you will find several hints about problems with graphic acceleration / GPU drivers. But that didn't help for me and thats's the reason why I wrote that drivers are up-to-date.